# Proguard returned with error code 1. See console Android

Tags: android, proguard

This question already have been asked many times but I am not able to resolve it. I am trying to export my app using eclipse for final release BUT I am getting the below error. I added all entries which others have suggested in other links but no help. Please help me how to get rid of this error.

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-08-24 11:21:11 - ] Note: there were 1035 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-08-24 11:21:11 - ] Warning:com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find superclass or interface javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable

[2014-08-24 11:21:11 - ] Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
[2014-08-24 11:21:11 - 
[2014-08-24 11:21:11 - ] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker
[2014-08-24 11:21:11 - ] Warning: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil

 You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
   Warning: there were 127 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
  Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

There was long error so I pasted relevant one. Below is my proguard-project.txt file entries.

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }   
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-keep class javax.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.** {*;}
-keep public class Mail {*;}        
-dontshrink
-dontwarn org.mockito.**
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn android.test.**
-keep class javax.ws.rs.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I added below two lines and now it is not giving any warning and I am able to generate .apk file successfully using eclipse.

```
-dontwarn javax.jdo.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.**
```

Hope it will help someone. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But can you explain why the errors happen. It didn't happen before I updated the newest Android SDK tool.

Comment: where you added these two lines?